# Taking all the real remaining space in a row

Tags: flutter, flexbox, row, expanded

I want to create a `Row` in Flutter with an avatar and some text. Currently, text is taking all remaining space horizontally with `Expanded`. I want to get rid of spacing on the left in the following example.

Note: Blue text "Atlas" is hardcoded. Rest of the content is coming from a database. You can think it's like a chat buble. Atlas is user name.

[image: example_1]

I've tried to use `Stack` but they are getting on top of each other that way which is not what I wanted. Is there any possible way to my `Expanded` take all space after the avatar vertically? Desired result is:

[image: example_2]

My current code is like this:

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Container(
          width: 45,
          height: 45,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Image.asset('image.png'),
          ),
        ),
      context.smallGap,
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Atlas',
            ),
            Text(
              'Rest of the text..',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is put image and texts (Column) Atlas & Flutter Learning Roadmap in a Row
Then that Row should be inside column along with other texts.

Something like following

```
Column([
  Row ([image, Column(Atlas, Flutter Learning Roamap)]),
  Phase 1...
  Flutter....
])
```

Comment: What you mentioned may only apply to hard coded strings. It is not always possible for me to know the length of the article and break it down into parts. "Atlas" text is not important in this case. It's all about the content

Comment: I think the images I gave as examples were not fully understandable. The blue "Atlas" text was written by hand. All other content comes from a database. You can think of it like a message bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I would go with Dhiraj's method where you can extract the title from the outsourced content and place it in `Row`, while the rest in a `column`.

```
String databaseContent = 'example';
String title = functionToGetTitle(databaseContent);
Column([
  Row ([image, Column(Atlas, title)]),
  databaseContent
]);
```

An alternative method is to use `Richtext` widget. Here you can use a list of `TextSpan` and have anything you want in between them using `WidgetSpan`

See a demo here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=a947443679a47862711cd1acd8a9ddfc